# React doesn't do anything after redirection

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I have a NavLink on its click it fires a function which redirects it to another page but upon redirection it doen't perform any task like console.log("Hi");

```
 <NavLink to="/data" onClick={this.performTask} exact ={
```

What do I do to perform these functions after redirection ?

```
performTask(event) {

    //browserHistory.push("/data/"+this.state.category1+'/'+this.state.zip1+'/'+this.state.age1+'/'+'/'+this.state.gender1);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state.zip1);
    console.log(this.state.age1);
    console.log("asd");
    console.log(window.location.href);
    fetch('/api/customers/'+this.state.category1+'/'+this.state.zip1+'/'+this.state.age1+'/'+'/'+this.state.gender1)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi @asd , if any of the answers resolve your issue, please mark them as the correct answers so other users to use in the future. If it wasn't answered, please add comments to the answers or here to see what else can be done to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect and then perform some actions within the same component.

A couple of workarounds:

**Redirect after performing the actions**

change performTask to:

```
performTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent first
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state.zip1);
    console.log(this.state.age1);
    console.log("asd");
    console.log(window.location.href);
    fetch('/api/customers/'+this.state.category1+'/'+this.state.zip1+'/'+this.state.age1+'/'+'/'+this.state.gender1)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
    // redirect 
    browserHistory.push("/data/" + this.state.category1 +'/' + this.state.zip1 + '/' + this.state.age1 + '/'+'/' + this.state.gender1);
}
```

if any of the previous task is async you have to wait:

```
async performTask(event) {
    await doAsync();
    // redirect 
    browserHistory.push("/data/" + this.state.category1 +'/' + this.state.zip1 + '/' + this.state.age1 + '/'+'/' + this.state.gender1); 
}
```

**Redirect and manage actions in the redirected component**

If you redirect to a given route, in the component which that route routes to, change the componentDidMount or componentWillReceiveProps functions depending on whether the component has been mounted already.

```
performTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent first
    fetch('/api/customers/' + this.state.category1 + '/' + this.state.zip1 + '/' + this.state.age1+'/' + '/' + this.state.gender1)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
    browserHistory.push("/data/" + this.state.category1 +'/' + this.state.zip1 + '/' + this.state.age1 + '/'+'/' + this.state.gender1);
}
```

and in your RedirectedComponent:

```
class RedirectedComponent extends Component {
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.performTasks();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
    this.performTasks();
}

performTasks(){
    // do things
    console.log('Hi');
}
```